# Separate project in two part with Apache tomcat

Tags: java, spring, apache, spring-mvc, tomcat

I have two part in my application : **administration** and **client** part.

- In administration the admins upload files and fill a form and make some others administration tools.
- In client side the users make a search over entities saved from administration part.

I run this in the same project with **tomcat server** but sometimes when uploading files i got `Java Heap` problem and the server get down and the users can't make search anymore until i restart the server and also i don't want charge the bandwidth with uploading files. And there is conflict between session variables and timeout.

So I want separate them into two **independent** projects

1. How to run two projects so if the admin project is down my clients continues to use my web app ?
2. And How can i call **commons services** (controllers) and **commons resources** (img, files, css, js, ...) between client & admin part ?

Comment: Try searching "Tomcat java heap" on google and you will see

Comment: @JIV I want separate them even if the java heap problem is solved

Comment: You can simply create two applications and then upload them in webapps.... Each of them will be refereed with their respective application names from front-end.

Comment: Separating apps on single Tomcat will not fix the issue when one app crashes whole tomcat. So probably what you want is to use 2 separate tomcat instances. Next trouble is, they will need different ports. It can be solved with some proxy server (i.e. look at apache httpd + AJP tomcat)

Comment: An alternative would be to 'package' Tomcat or Jetty with your application. Check Spring Boot for a quick solution or if you want to code it yourself, here is a nice tutorial: http://kielczewski.eu/2013/11/using-embedded-jetty-spring-mvc/ . Also, note that this is a technically equivalent solution to having two separate Tomcat deployments, the only difference is that you have programmatic control over ports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is very broad, so it's almost impossible to answer.

### Heap issues

First, the reason for heap issue might as well be that you're buffering the entire uploaded file in memory (i.e. you deserialize the uploaded image into `byte[]` or anything like that). This is something you never do with untrusted content or reasonable size limits, as someone might upload a 16GB file and destroy your RAM completely. Instead, you can stream the uploaded bytes either to disk or to something else that works with streams.

[`FileUpload` from Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/using.html) gives you a nice and simple way to take uploads of arbitrary size and dynamically decide whether to buffer them in memory or disk based on size:

```
// Create a factory for disk-based file items
DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

// Set factory constraints
factory.setSizeThreshold(yourMaxMemorySize);
factory.setRepository(yourTempDirectory);

// Create a new file upload handler
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

// Set overall request size constraint
upload.setSizeMax(yourMaxRequestSize);

// Parse the request
List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);
```

### Separating the apps

On the topic of separating applications, just make 2 WARs, no magic there. But keep in mind that **whatever crashes your app due to heap problems, is likely to crash the entire JVM**, so to isolate them, you'll need to **deloy them into separate JVMs** (i.e. separate Tomcat instances).

To share common classes, like controllers, just separate them into a JAR that both WARs depend on. A simple [maven multi-module project](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html) will do, one module for each WAR, and one for each shared JAR.

The resources you can share in a few ways:

- Also package them into a shared JAR under **`META-INF/resources`**: This is supported starting from Servlet 3.0. Here's a [detailed guide](https://alexismp.wordpress.com/2010/04/28/web-inflib-jarmeta-infresources/). This approach has the benefit of being simple to deploy, just treat the resources JAR as any other dependency. The down side is that it doesn't allow for easy redeployment without restarting the app.
- Deploy them to a shared drive: You have to manage a separate deployment, but you can always redeploy without affecting the app.

#### Shared JAR with static resources

If in your classpath (meaning inside `WEB-INF/lib/` of your WAR) you have a JAR that contains `META-INF/resources/image.jpg`, you'll be able to access it via:

`http://localhost:8080/<subcontext>/image.jpg`

See [the guide](https://alexismp.wordpress.com/2010/04/28/web-inflib-jarmeta-infresources/) for more details.

#### Shared external location

You can tell Tomcat to look for resources in an external location. The configuration is different for different Tomcat version:

- Using *aliases*

> ```
> <Context aliases="/images=/var/www/images" />
> ```

- The same configuration using Tomcat 8's `Resources`.

> ```
> <Context>
>   <Resources>
>     <PostResources className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet"
>                    base="/var/www/images" webAppMount="/images" />
>   </Resources>
> </Context>
> ```

You then put static resources into `/var/www/images` (e.g. `/var/www/images/image.jpg`) and access them via `http://localhost:8080/<subcontext>/images` (e.g. `http://localhost:8080/<subcontext>/images/image.jpg`).

See [this tutorial](http://mikusa.blogspot.nl/2014/07/tips-on-migrating-to-tomat-8-resources.html) for more examples.